# How do I save highscore into a file with python?

Tags: python, file

I'm working on a memory tile match game in python and want to save the name and score to a text file, which should be showed after every finished game. I have succeeded with saving the name and score in a text file (sorted), however "[NUL]" also appears in this text file; please find picture of my text file below.

[image]

These [NUL] are increasing with every added score, however with a varying amount every time.

Comment: I cannot recreate the problem since your code is missing the `Board` class, but can you try `file = open('./highscore.txt', 'w')`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a problem in this case, but you should still always explicitly close the file after using it with file.close().

Comment: There nothing evident here that would add nul characters (ascii 0 character) to the start of your file.  You should write a small program that reads the file, adds a name and score, and writes it back out (without all the game mechanics) and see if you get the same problem.

Comment: Did you try our suggestions?

Comment: Please **reduce** the code to the minimum to reproduce the problem.  The `score` function (with minor mods to not need the class) is all that is needed.

Comment: @mapf yes! I have now updated the code again. My only problem left is to print out a high score board after each finished game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open` requires an intervening `seek` to switch between reading and writing, and make sure to close the file:

```
def score(self):
    scores = []
    with open('highscore.txt','r+') as file:  # closes file when exit with
        for hs in file:                       # no need to readlines()
            name, counts = hs.split(",") 
            scores.append((name, int(counts)))
        scores.append((self.name, self.counts))
        scores.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1])
        file.seek(0)                          # seek to switch to writing
        file.truncate(0)
        for name, score in scores:
            line = name + "," + str(score)
            file.write(line + "\n")
```

You can also close and re-open the file for writing instead, and use a try/except to handle the case that `highscore.txt` is not created yet:

```
def score(self):
    scores = []
    try:
        with open('highscore.txt','r') as file:
            for hs in file:
                name, counts = hs.split(",") 
                scores.append((name, int(counts)))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass

    scores.append((self.name, self.counts))
    scores.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1])
    
    with open('highscore.txt','w') as file:
        for name, score in scores:
            line = name + "," + str(score)
            file.write(line + "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your first option works great! Do you have any idea where and how I should add code that prints out a high score board after each finished game?